# JavaScript: Rebuild Array of Objects using Reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that I'm trying to rebuild without any success:

```js
const data = [
    {
        ID: 1,
        TemplateName: 'Template 1',
        TemplateCategory: 'Category A',
    }, 
    {
        ID: 2,
        TemplateName: 'Template 2',
        TemplateCategory: 'Category A',
    }, 
    {
        ID: 3,
        TemplateName: 'Template 3',
        TemplateCategory: 'Category B',
    }, 
]
```

I have the below code which produces the following undesired result:

```js
    result = [...data
      .reduce((acc, {TemplateCategory, TemplateName, ID}) => {
          const group = acc.get(TemplateCategory)
          group ? group.options.push(ID, TemplateName) : acc.set(TemplateCategory, {TemplateCategory, "options":[ID, TemplateName]})
          return acc
        }, new Map)
      .values()
    ]

console.log(result) // undesired result:
[
    {
        TemplateCategory: 'Category A',
        options: [1, 'Template 1', 2, 'Template 2']
    },
    {
        TemplateCategory: 'Category B',
        options: [3, 'Template 3']
    }
]
```

I am stuck on trying to convert `options` to an Array of Objects with `value` and `label` as properties. Also im struggling trying to reword `TemplateCategory` property to `label`.

My desired result is:

```js
[
    {
        label: 'Category A',
        options: [
            {
                value: 1,
                label: 'Template 1'
            },
            {
                value: 2,
                label: 'Template 2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'Category B',
        options: [
            {
                value: 3,
                label: 'Template 3'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```js
const data = [
    {
        ID: 1,
        TemplateName: 'Template 1',
        TemplateCategory: 'Category A',
    }, 
    {
        ID: 2,
        TemplateName: 'Template 2',
        TemplateCategory: 'Category A',
    }, 
    {
        ID: 3,
        TemplateName: 'Template 3',
        TemplateCategory: 'Category B',
    }, 
]

const result = [...data
      .reduce((acc, {TemplateCategory, TemplateName, ID}) => {
          const group = acc.get(TemplateCategory)
          group ? group.options.push({value: ID, label: TemplateName}) : acc.set(TemplateCategory, {label: TemplateCategory, "options":[{value: ID, label: TemplateName}]})
          return acc
        }, new Map)
      .values()
    ]

console.log(result) // undesired result:
```

Comment: Hello, I have run the code snippet as I required similar output but showing [object] in options Array. please show me where to fix it

Comment: @sda87 this is not right place to ask a question. You need to post your code, sample data, expected output, where get stuck, etc in your question. And in this particular code snippet, the options array is indeed an array of objects, e.g. `typeof {}`